# Validation summary is not working

Tags: asp.net

I didn't get the "'*' - Required Field Can't Be Left Blank" as my output when I execute the form, eventhough I left the required textbox blank , please try to help me...

This is my validation summary code:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" 
     ForeColor="Red" HeaderText="'*' - Required Field Can't Be Left Blank" 
     EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Also, where is the code....

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `RequiredFieldValidator` control to your textbox and then only `ValidationSummary` will show the result

If you using `ValidationGroup` for `RequiredFieldValidator` then you must give the same in ValidationSummary and the button as well

Comment: Yup I used it too...


          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"      runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="*"   Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: @Jiya give the same `ValidationGroup` for  `ValidationSummary` control and the button control you submit the page

Comment: @Jiya now you get the results as expected?

Comment: Damith I only need the HeaderText, but it s coming with some bullets :(

Comment: Do you have many controls to validate? summary is design for list all the validation errors. if you need validate one text box then you don't need summary control. RequiredFieldValidator will show the error , place it where you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31447/discussion-between-damith-and-jiya)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code in your page's head section.
and please note that **#ValidationSummary1** is Id of validation summary control. If you have provided other Id than this. place do change accordingly.
this will display error summary without bullet-list.

```
<style type="text/css">
#ValidationSummary1 ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
```